# how to correctly target specific buttons on wordpress site to customise css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to style certain buttons on my wordpress site by adding in custom css in the customiser.

The block of code where my buttons are nested is

```
<div class="xoo-cp-container">
    <div class="xoo-cp-outer">
        <div class="xoo-cp-cont-opac"></div>
        <span class="xoo-cp-preloader xoo-cp-icon-spinner"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="xoo-cp-close xoo-cp-icon-cross"></span>

    <div class="xoo-cp-content" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="xoo-cp-atcn xoo-cp-success"><span class="xoo-cp-icon-check"></span>Product successfully added to your cart</div>


<table class="xoo-cp-pdetails clearfix">
<tbody><tr data-xoo_cp_key="7f5d04d189dfb634e6a85bb9d9adf21e">
    <td class="xoo-cp-remove"><span class="xoo-cp-icon-cross xoo-cp-remove-pd"></span></td>
    <td class="xoo-cp-pimg"><a href="#"><img width="300" height="450" src="#" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="#"></a></td>
    <td class="xoo-cp-ptitle"><a href="#">Gin - Case 12x 5cl&nbsp;</a>

    
    </td><td class="xoo-cp-pprice"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>99.00</bdi></span></td>


    <td class="xoo-cp-pqty">
                        <div class="xoo-cp-qtybox">
            <span class="xcp-minus xcp-chng">-</span>
            <input type="number" class="xoo-cp-qty" max="" min="1" step="1" value="2" pattern="[0-9]*">
            <span class="xcp-plus xcp-chng">+</span></div>
                </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="xoo-cp-ptotal"><span class="xcp-totxt">Total : </span><span class="xcp-ptotal"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>198.00</bdi></span></span></div>

</div>
        
        
    <div class="xoo-cp-btns">
        <a class="xoo-cp-btn-vc xcp-btn" href="#">View Cart</a>
        <a class="xoo-cp-btn-ch xcp-btn" href="#">Checkout</a>
        <a class="xoo-cp-close xcp-btn">Continue Shopping</a>
    </div>
        </div>
```

and the buttons I'm trying to style are located at the end of the code block

```
<div class="xoo-cp-btns">
    <a class="xoo-cp-btn-vc xcp-btn" href="#">View Cart</a>
    <a class="xoo-cp-btn-ch xcp-btn" href="#">Checkout</a>
    <a class="xoo-cp-close xcp-btn">Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
```

i've tried to style each of them in the following way

```
.xoo-cp-btn-vc{background:green!important; color:white!important;}
a.xoo-cp-btn-vc{background:green!important; color:white!important;}
.xoo-cp-btns .xoo-cp-btn-vc{background:green!important; color:white!important;}
a.xoo-cp-btns .xoo-cp-btn-vc{background:green!important; color:white!important;}
```

but none of them are correct, can someone please help me correctly target the correct elements please.

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Link to the page? Maybe it's in an iframe or something which you won't be able to control. What you're doing seems to be correct

Comment: ah i bet that's what it is then, its a plugin which shows contents of the basket when something is added. the site is remedispirits.co.uk

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to be the issue at all, where are you adding your styles? I can't find them. If I edit the DOM in the Chrome Dev Tools and add the following `<style>.xoo-cp-btn-vc { background: green !important; color: white !important; }</style>` it seems to work just fine for me?

Comment: Actually, if this is for the gold button in your custom CSS then the selector is wrong, try this `.xoo-cp-container .xoo-cp-close.xcp-btn {background:gold;}` if an element has multiple selectors that you are targeting the don't add a space between them

Comment: it seems like there was an issue with the cache, despite clearing it in my browser several times. Its now working using simply .xoo-cp-close :( why it didn't work an hour ago is beyond me

Comment: That will affect the little close button and the continue shopping shopping button. Glad it's working now though -- if you have a caching plugin setup on your site then you need to purge that as well. Browser cache and server cache are different -- glad it's all working!

Answer (score 0):

a good way to find how they are currently styled is to hop in the inspector.

In the styles section you can see what the classes used to select the button currently are. So when trying to overwrite these classes you'll have to make sure your selectors are weighted more heavily than the existing ones.

The importance of css selectors is as follows

```
100 points for IDs
10 points for classes and pseudo-classes
1 point for tag selectors and pseudo-elements
Note: If the element has inline styling that automatically wins (1000 
points)
```

So if there is currently 5 classes pointing to your button those styles will have a weight of 50 while your `a.xoo-cp-btn-vc` class selector has a weight of 20 for having the `a` and the `.xoo-cp-btn-vc`

Adding specificity to your selectors should help, and if you use the exact same selectors that are currently used the `!important` should be enough to overwright them

Comment: ok thanks for your help, i'll try and add more selectors and see if that helps :)

Comment: i've just tried .xoo-cp-container .xoo-cp-btn a.xoo-cp-close{background:gold!important;} but im not sure if im using the a correctly and should i be using > between sectors?

Comment: The > between selectors means that everything after > has to be a direct child of the class selectors that come before >

Comment: ah ok thanks :) seems my issue was due to a cache problem its now working as expected :)

Comment: Good find! Pesky caches have ruined my day a time or 2 as well haha